# Remove Rows Based On Condition on Azure Data Explorer

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

In Azure Data Explorer, I am trying to remove rows from a table which the rows contain language == "en-us". Here's the syntax:

```
.delete table tableName records <| tableName | where language == "en-us"
```

But I got this error:

> ```
>     "code": "BadRequest_SyntaxError",
>     "message": "Request is invalid and cannot be executed.",
>     "@type": "Kusto.Data.Exceptions.SyntaxException",
>     "@message": "Syntax error: ",
> ```

What should be the right syntax? I followed this tutorial: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-explorer-blog/deleting-individual-records-in-a-table/ba-p/3166847

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cannot delete records from tables with data in V2 format

The soft delete feature is only available on ADX clusters that are running on Engine V3.  Refer the [Limitations and considerations for deletion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/concepts/data-soft-delete#limitations-and-considerations).

> In General Availability (GA), new clusters are created in EngineV3 mode by default. SLA applies to all EngineV3 and EngineV2 production clusters. To migrate EngineV2 clusters, please [create a support ticket](https://ms.portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.Support). The migration process itself requires minimal downtime of less than a minute and does not have material impact on ingestion and query performance.

**Reference:** [Azure Data Explorer Kusto EngineV3 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/Engine-v3)

Answer (score 1):

I just tried out the below syntax and it went through fine:

.delete table tableName records <| tableName | where ['language'] == "en-us"

Comment: I got this error after using your syntax: Cannot delete records from tables with data in V2 format. Do you know what that means?